# remove all spawned coins

Tags: lua, coronasdk

What is the best way to remove all spawned coins when the game is over?

Here is the code that spawns the coins:

```
 screenGroup = self.view
 coin = {}
 coinspawn = function()
 i = display.newSprite( imageSheet1, sequenceData1 )

    i.x = display.contentWidth
    i.y = math.random(0, display.contentHeight-50)
    i:play()
    i.collided = true
    i.name = "coin"
    physics.addBody(i, "dynamic", 
        {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, shape= shape2 ,filter=playerCollisionFilter } 
    )   
    --player.gravityScale = 0.5
    coinIntro = transition.to(i,{time=2500, x=display.contentWidth - display.contentWidth -500  ,onComplete=jetReady , transition=easing.OutExpo } ) --
    coin[#coin+1] = i

end 
tmrcoin = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, coinspawn, 0 )
```

Comment: please remember, in future questions, to show what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would remove all coins from the display. Then you would clear the `coin` table:

```
for i=1,#coin do 
    coin[i]:removeSelf()
end
coin = {}  -- forget all coins
```

Assuming `coin` table is the only other place you store your coins, this will do it.

Note that you can't use `coin[i]=nil` in the loop after `removeSelf`: as soon as table has holes, the # operator is basically unusable. You can't use table.remove either, because i gets incremented every time, so you'll miss items (try, you'll see). Same issue with pairs: you can't edit a table while iterating through it. You could however do this:

```
local numCoins = #coin
for i=1,numCoins do 
    coin[i]:removeSelf()
    coin[i]=nil
end
-- now coin is {}
```

The only reason I can think of to nil N items instead of letting the gc take care of it with one `table = {}` statement is if you have more than one reference to your coin table (which I would rename to coins, BTW, for clarity).

Comment: for some reason a get a 'Attempt to call method 'removeSelf' (a nil value)' error but 'coin = {}' on its own seems to do the trick

Comment: @kevinver That error means some important code not shown because the `for i=1,#coin` construct will only loop over first N non-nil items of table starting with `coin[1]`. Does other code remove items from `coin` table? If so  you must use ipairs(). Also if you don't call `removeSelf()` you will get a leak, may not be evident until you've restarted scene many times (without exiting). Unless (again in code not shown in your question, such as in a destroyScene event handler) you destroy the scene view which makes the `removeSelf()` unnecessary.

Comment: sorry i was trying to remove them using "coin[i] = nil" so i think the combination whit  "coin = {}" fixed the problem

Comment: and the game is in one lua file so i'm not exiting the scene

Comment: Do you see `coin[i]=nil in my code`? There is a reason :) I've extended post.